# convert a list of objects from one type to another using lambda expression

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

I have a foreach loop reading a list of objects of one type and producing a list of objects of a different type. I was told that a lambda expression can achieve the same result.

```
var origList = List<OrigType>(); // assume populated
var targetList = List<TargetType>(); 

foreach(OrigType a in origList) {
    targetList.Add(new TargetType() {SomeValue = a.SomeValue});
}
```

Comment: @mmcrae that question is newer than this one

Answer (score 402):

Try the following

```
var targetList = origList
  .Select(x => new TargetType() { SomeValue = x.SomeValue })
  .ToList();
```

This is using a combination of Lambdas and LINQ to achieve the solution.  The Select function is a projection style method which will apply the passed in delegate (or lambda in this case) to every value in the original collection.  The result will be returned in a new `IEnumerable<TargetType>`.  The .ToList call is an extension method which will convert this `IEnumerable<TargetType>` into a `List<TargetType>`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having a concrete implementation for `TargetType`? I've ended up with something like this: `List<ISearchEntity> results = myIQueryable.Select(x => (ISearchEntity) new TargetType { MyField = "Field value is " + x.TargetField }).ToList();` where the goal was to get an object of type `List<ISearchEntity>`

Comment: How can this be adapted to work with an anonymous type as a target type? Is that possible?

Answer (score 268):

If you *know* you want to convert from `List<T1>` to `List<T2>` then [`List<T>.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx) will be slightly more efficient than `Select`/`ToList` because it knows the exact size to start with:

```
target = orig.ConvertAll(x => new TargetType { SomeValue = x.SomeValue });
```

In the more general case when you only know about the source as an `IEnumerable<T>`, using `Select`/`ToList` is the way to go. You *could* also argue that in a world with LINQ, it's more idiomatic to start with... but it's worth at least being aware of the `ConvertAll` option.

Comment: at first i didn't think i could do this, because i was dealing with an ienumerable (for the source list and it doesnt provide a convertall option) so i called .ToList() on it and now i'm trying convertall - i like it better than putting in a non-filtering 'where'

Comment: Why would you need a where? If you've only got `IEnumerable<T>` then just call `Select` and `ToList` as per Jared's answer.

Comment: For other newbies like me, you can also call a method like `x => buildTargetType(x)`

Comment: Best One Liner!

Answer (score 72):

```
var target = origList.ConvertAll(x => (TargetType)x);
```

Comment: What is this syntax ? This does not ressemble a lambda. Some documentation link would be appreciated. Thanks though, it works fine here

Comment: The argument to ConvertAll is a regular C# lambda, right?

Comment: looks nice, but needs some context around when (or if) it can be used. I just tried it and was getting a `cannot cast expression` exception

Comment: Savage cast... please don't or explain with a real example and comment what the user needs to adapt

Answer (score 40):

```
List<target> targetList = new List<target>(originalList.Cast<target>());
```

Comment: -1 this would only work if casting was possible and in the OPs case it does appear be so.

Comment: Works as expected ! needed to convert List<object> to List<RealType>

Comment: Note that this answer only works if `TargetType` is a base type of `OrigType`. Can be simplified to `... = originalList.Cast<TargetType>().ToList();`

Answer (score 21):

I believe something like this should work:

```
origList.Select(a => new TargetType() { SomeValue = a.SomeValue});
```

Comment: You need to add a `.ToList()` at the end, otherwise this will simply provide an IEnumerable.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a simple example..

```
List<char> c = new List<char>() { 'A', 'B', 'C' };

List<string> s = c.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: Awesome... exactly what I was looking for! Well not quite exactly... I just wanted a property of each Element in the list, but you gave me the lamba syntax without having to scroll too far. ;)

Answer (score 7):

```
var list1 = new List<Type1>();
var list2 = new List<Type2>();

list1.ForEach(item => list2.Add(new Type2() { Prop1 = value1 }));
```

Answer (score 3):

Assume that you have multiple properties you want to convert.

```
public class OrigType{
    public string Prop1A {get;set;}
    public string Prop1B {get;set;}
}

public class TargetType{
    public string Prop2A {get;set;}
    public string Prop2B {get;set;}
}

var list1 = new List<OrigType>();
var list2 = new List<TargetType>();

list1.ConvertAll(x => new OrigType { Prop2A = x.Prop1A, Prop2B = x.Prop1B })
```

Answer (score 3):

Or with a `constructor` & `linq` with `Select`:

```
public class TargetType {
  public string Prop1 {get;set;}
  public string Prop1 {get;set;}

  // Constructor
  public TargetType(OrigType origType) {
    Prop1 = origType.Prop1;
    Prop2 = origType.Prop2;
  }
}

var origList = new List<OrigType>();
var targetList = origList.Select(s=> new TargetType(s)).ToList();
```

The `Linq` line is more soft! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use a function to cast:

```
var list1 = new List<Type1>();
var list2 = new List<Type2>();

list2 = list1.ConvertAll(x => myConvertFuntion(x));
```

Where my custom function is:

```
private Type2 myConvertFunction(Type1 obj){
   //do something to cast Type1 into Type2
   return new Type2();
}
```

Comment: It's possible to shorten even further, `list2 = list1.ConvertAll(myConvertFuntion);`

Answer (score 1):

for similar type class.

`List<targetlist> targetlst= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<targetlist>>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(<List<baselist>));`

Comment: Thank you very much. It is expensive as hell for server and it is not according to best practices, but works splendidly. I used it for converting EF database first classes when multiple procedures return the same 5 columns as a result, only for different "where clauses" in the procedures. I know I should have made table type on the database, but I wasn't the designer of that..

Answer (score 0):

If the types can be directly cast this is the cleanest way to do it:

```
var target = yourList.ConvertAll(x => (TargetType)x);
```

If the types can't be directly cast then you can map the properties from the orginal type to the target type.

```
var target = yourList.ConvertAll(x => new TargetType { SomeValue = x.SomeValue });
```

Answer (score 0):

If casting when mapping from one list to another is required, from convertall, you can call a function to test the casting.

```
public int StringToInt(String value)
        {
            try
            {
                return Int32.Parse(value);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        [Fact]
        public async Task TestConvertAll()
        { 
            List<String> lstString = new List<String>{"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10" };

            List<int> lstInt = lstString.ConvertAll(new Converter<String, int>(StringToInt));
            foreach (var item in lstInt)
            {
                output.WriteLine("{0}", item);
            }
            if (lstInt.Count()>0) {
                Assert.True(true);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

We will consider first List type is String and want to convert it to Integer type of List.

```
List<String> origList = new ArrayList<>(); // assume populated
```

Add values in the original List.

```
origList.add("1");
origList.add("2");
    origList.add("3");
    origList.add("4");
    origList.add("8");
```

Create target List of Integer Type

```
List<Integer> targetLambdaList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
targetLambdaList=origList.stream().map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Print List values using forEach:

```
    targetLambdaList.forEach(System.out::println);
```