# Converting Between List Types in C#

Tags: c#, list, generics, type-conversion

I have the following classes:

```
ClassA
ClassB
ClassC
```

And then all inherit from:

```
ParentClass
```

At a point in my code I have a property called MyLists that's of type Object, declared like:

```
Object MyLists = null;
```

It's value can be any of the following types:

```
List<ClassA>
List<ClassB>
List<ClassC>
```

I was hoping to do something like:

```
foreach(ParentClass o in MyLists)
    //yada yada
```

But unfortunately that doesn't seem possible.  I get a runtime error stating:

```
Can't convert from List<ClassA> to List<ParentClass>
```

I'd prefer not ending up with code like:

```
if(MyLists is List<ClassA>)
{
    // blah blah
}
else if(MyLists is List<ClassB>)
{
    // blah blah
}
:
:
```

How can I convert MyLists into List?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert a list of objects from one type to another using lambda expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909268/convert-a-list-of-objects-from-one-type-to-another-using-lambda-expression)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to enumerate the values you can do

```
foreach(var parent in (IEnumerable<ParentClass>)MyLists)
{
}
```

You could avoid the cast if you changed the type of `MyLists` to `IEnumerable<ParentClass>`.

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
Object MyLists = null;
```

with this

```
IList<ParentClass> MyLists = null;
```

instantiate `MyLists` like this:

```
MyLists = new List<ParentClass>();
```

now can add instances of `ParentClass`, `ClassA` etc.

Comment: It creates an reference to a class implementing IList<ParentClass>, so your foreach loop compiles and you can insert instances of all of your derived classes

Comment: This won't compile, you can't assign a `List<Child>` to an `IList<Parent>` since `IList<T>` is not covariant.

Comment: This is the correct use of polymorphism. In general in .NET, if you're casting, you're probably using a bad pattern.

Comment: @Lee but you can iterate `List<Child>` and add the elements to `IList<Parent>` if `Child : Parent`

Comment: @Lee: Since he just wanted to iterate ParentClasses my intention was to instantiate with List<ParentClass> and add ClassA, ClassB and ClassC instances. Will edit my answer to clarify

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of `MyLists` to `IEnumerable<ParentClass>`. Since `IEnumerable<T>` is [covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this can work.

```
IEnumerable<ParentClass> MyLists = null;
// fill it with one of the list types
foreach (var item in MyLists)
    // do something
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that MyLists will not be Object but a List of ParentClass  your challenge has already been described and solved in the below article:
[Convert List<DerivedClass> to List<BaseClass>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817300/convert-listderivedclass-to-listbaseclass)

Answer (score -1):

First cast the objects in each list to ParentClass. Then, add them together. Then you can enumerate your list:

```
var castedlistA = listA.Cast<ParentClass>();
var castedlistB = listB.Cast<ParentClass>();
var castedlistC = listC.Cast<ParentClass>();

var fullList = castedListA.AddRange(castedListB).AddRange(castedListC);

foreach (var item in fullList)
{
    //Do something
}
```