# Copying a C# Collection to another collection

Tags: c#

I have the following list/Collection which I need to copy into another list.But the list are not having the same number of parameters. But the name of the object and types are same. Here is the class

**First Class:**

```
public class Class1
{
  int locationID{get;set;}
  string locationName{get;set;}
}
```

**Second Class:**

```
public class Class2
{
  int locationID{get;set;}
  string locationName{get;set;}
  string identifier{get;set;}
}
```

In my method, I need to get the value of the List1 and Copy the same to List2(Class2). List2 is having an extra parameter **identifier**.
How can this be implemented in C#??

Comment: You want to copy a `List<Class1>` to a `List<Class2>`? Are they related? Is `Class1` a parent of `Class2`? Do give us more context.

Comment: Well what do you want the value of the identifier to be for each item in list2? (As an aside, I'd very strongly urge you to start following .NET naming conventions, and adding spaces around punctuation...)

Comment: I don't see any collections? What should be placed in identifier? Mind that objects sharing the same properties can probably be resolved by using *inheritance*.

Comment: There are some contradictions. What are "list parameters"? How can the type be the same if you have two classes? Show how you fill the lists and your desired result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert a list of objects from one type to another using lambda expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909268/convert-a-list-of-objects-from-one-type-to-another-using-lambda-expression)

Comment: @TimSchmelter : I simply want to convert the type of class1 to class2 which have two different objects.

Comment: It seems to me that Class2 should be a subclass of Class1. Poof. All your problems disappear.

Comment: You can just loop through all the list items of List<Class1> and create a class2 object and add it to List<Class2>. I can help you with code if you want. But I think there is a problem with your approach.

Comment: I have posted this simply to avoid the foreach loop. If I wanna use foreach loop,my job would become simple. Since there might be more than 1000 items inside the collection, I don't want the collection to be iterated. Is there a way to copy the object value from one to another?

Comment: @Sriram M, even the simplest possible code in the best case scenario ,passing one list in to the constructor of another list, is going to iterate the list internally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var l1 = new List<Class1>();
var l2 = new List<Class2>();

l2.AddRange(l1.Select(i=>new Class2() {locationID = i.locationID,
                                       locationName = i.locationName});
```

Comment: This worked fine. Thanks @Bradley

Answer (score 4):

If the types `Class1` and `Class2` are formally unrelated, the conversion has to be implemented manually, which can be done using Linq as follows.

```
var NewList
  = OldList.Select(
      x => new Class2{ locationID = x.locationID, locationName = x.locationName }
                  ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Class1 and Class2 two are two different objects and signatures and cannot just be copied from one to another.  What you will need to do is iterate over one list, crate a new object, copy the property values over, and add it to the other list.

```
var firstList = GetFirstList() //returns List<Class1>();
var secondList = new List<Class2>();

foreach(var first in firstList)
{
    var second = new Class2();
    second.locationID = first.locationID;
    second.locationName = first.locationName;

    //you could even set the identifier property here
    second.identifier = someValue;

    secondList.Add(second);
}
```