# How can I convert a list of Models to another list of Models that inherits from it?

Tags: c#, list, model-view-controller, model

I have a piece of code that retrieves a long list of members via a library.

```
public List<InstinctGuildMember> PrepareGuildMembersList()
        {
            List<GuildMember> warcraftGuildMembers = _warcraftClient.GetGuildRosterAsync("dragonmaw", "instinct", "profile-eu")
                                            .Result.Value.Members.OrderBy(members => members.Rank)
                                            .ThenBy(members => members.Character.Name)
                                            .ToList();

            // We cast a new List from our old List.
            List<InstinctGuildMember> instinctGuildMembers = new List<InstinctGuildMember>(warcraftGuildMembers.Cast<InstinctGuildMember>());

            return instinctGuildMembers;
        }
```

```
namespace guild_instinct.Models.GuildData
{
    public class InstinctGuildMember : GuildMember
    {
        public string RankName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The reason I want to convert to my own Model is because the provided Model does not have all the information I need. A friend of mine suggested making my own Model and inheriting the model from the library.

[image: An example of the GuildMember Model]

I found this solution on a [related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909268/convert-a-list-of-objects-from-one-type-to-another-using-lambda-expression). However, I couldn't get it to work as I kept receiving the error following error

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'ArgentPonyWarcraftClient.GuildMember' to type 'guild_instinct.Models.GuildData.InstinctGuildMember'.'

It's likely that I just lack the knowledge so far to do it correctly and the answer is staring me in the face.

I am clueless on how to continue. What knowledge should I delve into to further my progress? Am I in the right direction but do I lack some fundamentals to make it work? I hope my question is concise enough to warrant help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast the original list that way, since a `GuildMember` instance is not a `InstinctGuidMember`.

You can use **projection**, i.e. project the original list onto a new list of a different type:

```cs
var instinctGuildMembers = warcraftGuildMembers.Select(x => new InstinctGuildMember(x, rank)).ToList();
```

To have your model contain data from `GuildMember` **and** additional data, there are 2 ways:

Composition - Make your model **have** a `GuildMember` instance.

```cs
class InstinctGuildMember {
    private GuildMember _guildMember;
    private string _rankName;

    public InstinctGuildMember(GuildMember guildMember, string rankName)
    {
        _guildMember = guildMember;
        _rankName = rankName;
    }
}
```

Inheritance - Make your model **be** a `GuildMember` by inheriting the type.

```cs
class InstinctGuildMember : GuildMember {
    private string _rankName;

    //the constructor here depends on what constructors are available on GuildMember.
}
```

Comment: Hello, I tried your solution and it tells me that InstinctGuildMember doesn't have a constructor that takes 2 arguments. Seems logical, because it's just a model; what kind of constructor should I supply for this projection?

Comment: @shinyshark I added an example for a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast but you can convert.

```
List<InstinctGuildMember> instinctGuildMembers =
    warcraftGuildMembers.ConvertAll<InstinctGuildMember>(ConvertFunction);
```

And for `ConvertFunction` :

```
static InstinctGuildMember ConvertFunction(GuildMember x)
{
    InstinctGuildMember y = new InstinctGuildMember();
    y.prop1 = x.prop1;
    y.prop2 = x.prop2;
    y.RankName = "";
    return y;
}
```