# Best algorithm to convert a list of one type which is flat to another type which is hierarchical in C#

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I have a class Type1 that looks like this

```
public Class Type1{
   public string Key {get; set; }
   public List<string> Values {get; set; }
}
```

I want to convert/merge the List of Type1 with distinct Keys property and merge/append Values.

```
[
  {
    "key": "Key1",
    "value": ["value1"]
  },
  {
    "key": "Key2",
    "value": ["value2"]
  },
  {
    "key": "Key1",
    "value": ["value3"]
  }
]
```

The end result should be this

```
[
  {
    "key": "Key1",
    "values": 
        ["value1","value2"]
  },
  {
    "key": "Key2",
    "values": ["value2"]
  }
]
```

I am trying to use a dictionary here with linq but not getting what I want.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far; You could try: iterate through the flat list; if the second list already has the key from list 1 add it as a child else add it as a parent. Initially the second list is empty so it will also add the first item.

Comment: This post may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909268/convert-a-list-of-objects-from-one-type-to-another-using-lambda-expression

Comment: I suggest you divide the problem. Write a method which converts a single item into the hierarchical item. Then write a for loop that calls this function for all the elements in your list.

Comment: I used automapper to convert Type1 to Type2 with duplicate keys but having only one item in the Values property. Is there a way to merge these to a single list. For example the list after mapping has key1--> (single item in Values Property)Value1, key1 --> (Single item in Values property) Value2. How can we iterative or using Linq merge them to Key1 ---> Value1,Value2

Answer (score 1):

Using just LINQ would make it unreadable. The answer should look something like this:

```
List<Type1> input = ...;

var resultDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
foreach (var item in input)
{
    List<string> value;
    if (resultDictionary.TryGetValue(item.Key, out value))
        value.Add(item.Values[0]);
    else
        resultDictionary.Add(item.Key, new List<string>() { item.Values[0] });
}

return resultDictionary.Select(x => new Type1() { Key = x.Key, Values = x.Value }).ToList();
```