# How to cast a list or array to a subtype in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, casting

I have a class with a member for a list of objects. Lets say i have an Animal base class and subtypes of Cat and Dog. The list will always contain only Dogs or only Cats but i do not know up front.

```
class MyClass {

    public readonly List<Animal> Data = new();

    public void MethodForDogs()
    {
        Data.Add(new Dog());
    }

    public void MethodForCats()
    {
        Data.Add(new Cat());
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        HelperClass.DoIt(Data);
    }
}

class HelperClass {

    public static void DoIt(List<Animals> data) {

        if (data[0].GetType() == typeof(Cat) ) {
            var arrayCats = new Cat[data.Count];
            int i = 0;
            foreach (Animal item in data) {
                arrayCats[i++] = (Cat) item;
            }
            // use arrayCats
            ..
        }
        else if (data[0].GetType() == typeof(Dog) {
           // same, then use arrayDogs
           ..
        }
    }
}
```

what did NOT work was a direct cast, like

```
var arrayCats = (Cat[])data.ToArray();
```

even though i can check that all members are Cats. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297231/convert-string-to-int-in-one-line-of-code-using-linq - Would this help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert a list of objects from one type to another using lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909268/convert-a-list-of-objects-from-one-type-to-another-using-lambda-expression)

Comment: If you're sure that your array only contains cats, `var output = data.Cast<Cat>()`. If you just want to take the cats out, `var output = data.OfType<Cat>()`

Comment: @MarkusE That's a slightly different problem, as that question is about parsing strings to ints, whereas this one is just a normal reference conversion. Sinatr, good question but all of the answers are a bit rubbish. The closest, which uses `Cast<T>()`, uses `new List<T>(x.Cast<T>())` instead of `x.Cast<T>().ToList()`, and is hidden in the noise

Comment: `The list will always contain only Dogs or only Cats but i do not know up front.`. If you have to say this you have something inherently wrong with your use of polymorphism. If it's always an enumerable list of either `T : A` or `T : B`, you should probably be using [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) somewhere or restructure the way you're using polymorphism somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it the following way:

```
class HelperClass
{
    public static void DoIt(List<Animals> data)
    {
         if(data.All(a => a is Dog))
         {
              Dog[] dogs = data.OfType<Dog>().ToArray();
              // do something with dogs
         }
         else if(data.All(a => a is Cat))
         {
              Cat[] cats= data.OfType<Cat>().ToArray();
              // do something with cats
         }
         else
         {
            throw new ArgumentException("data must contain items of the same type");
         }
     }
}
```

With `All`, you check whether all items of your list fulfill a condition (in your case the type). `OfType()` gets you all items which have a certain type (in your case: all items) automatically casted to that type. If the list is of mixed type, the method will throw an exception (of course, you can use another error handling that fits more to your needs).

But you should also consider @AlphaDelta's comment. To me, it seems a bit strange that you have this list containg only one subtype.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and this detailed answer, that was what i was looking for. The use case is that at the end i want to build a JSON object for an external interface, which in itself is poorly designed because it accepts different datatypes under the same name, depending on the context. So i can choose to map it in a not too nice way to objects with some duplication (which i did) or then i could do nice polymorphism and then do some additional Json wrangling when i try to convert my objects to the foreign JSON. But that code would be more difficult to maintain for me.